# Wrap object in custom Python and then add extra logic

Tags: python, oop, design-patterns

A Python library provides a function `create_object` that creates an object of type `OriginalClass`.

I would like to create my own class so that it takes the output of `create_object` and adds extra logic (on top of what `create_object` already does). Also, that new custom object should have all the properties of the base object.

So far I've attempted the following:

```
class MyClass(OriginalClass):
  
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MyClass, self).__init__(args, kwargs)
```

This does not accomplish what I have in mind. Since the function `create_object` is not called and the extra logic handled by it not executed.

Also, I do not want to attach the output of `create_object` to an attribute of `MyClass` like so `self.myobject = create_object()`, since I want it to be accessed by just the instantiation of an object of type `MyClass`.

What would be the best way to achieve that functionality in Python? Does that corresponds to an existing design pattern?

*I am new to Python OOP so maybe the description provided is too vague. Please feel free to request in depth description from those vaguely described parts.*

Comment: What arguments does `create_object` take? What is the purpose of that function vs. simply instantiate the `OriginalClass`, i.e. does it perform something extra (maybe preprocessing the arguments)? Ideally a reference to code/documentation would be useful in order to help.

Comment: Also, for python3 `super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)` should be enough. Note the unpacking of `args` and `kwargs` - actually I guess that's the problem with your code. You need to unpack `args` and `kwargs` when calling `__init__()`

Comment: @buran Instantianting `OriginalClass` just calls the `__init__` of that class. Meanwhile, calling `create_object` instantiates in the first place an `OriginalClass` object and adds logic to it using functions that should not be exposed to the client. I do not want to call those internal functions from `MyClass`. Also, `create_object` accepts arguments that the `__init__` does not. I think this was done intentionally by the library devs to force clients use the `create_object` function.

Comment: @buran But the `__init__` does not call `create_object`, thus that extra logic I want to reuse is not executed. And that logic is executed by internal functions that should not be used by the client (`MyClass`).

Comment: Depending on how much access you have to the internal details of an `OriginalClass` instance, you might just want a `MyClass.create_object` class method that calls `super().create_object`, then does what you need to the resulting instance.

Comment: However, the fact that `create_object` exists at all (instead of just instantiating `OriginalClass` directly) may be an indication that `OriginalClass` does *not* expose the necessary details as part of its public interface. Proceed at your own risk.

Comment: (or `create_object`, if it's a regular function and not a class method of `OriginalClass`)

Comment: @chepner The specific code can be found here: https://pytorch.org/vision/0.11/_modules/torchvision/models/squeezenet.html#squeezenet1_0. `create_object` is in fact `squeezenet1_0`. It seems like the `OriginalClass` (`SqueezeNet`) is in charge only of generating different types of that object (version 1.0 or 1.1). And all the extra logic of `create_bject` is dedicated to override or set some predefined values (the pretrained weights of the network). Does that address your worryings? Or by the contrary did I not understand what could go wrong?

Comment: `create_object` is in fact a regular function that is in the same module as `OriginalClass`.

Comment: Looking at the original, I have an idea (though I would have defined those functions as class methods). I can't write it up right now, but will do so later if nobody else posts something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
class MyClass(OriginalClass):
    def __init__(self, custom_arg, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.init(custom_arg)
    def init(self, custom_arg):
        # add subclass initialization logic here
        self._custom_arg = custom_arg
    def my_class_method(self):
        pass

obj = create_object()
obj.__class__ = MyClass
obj.init(custom_arg)

obj.original_class_method()
obj.my_class_method()
```

You can change the `__class__` attribute of an object *if you know what you're doing*.

If I was you I would consider using an Adapter design pattern. It's maybe longer to code, but it's easier to maintain and understand.

Comment: Is there a way that all that is handled inside the class itself? Or is that constrained by the expressivity of the language?

Comment: @rober_dinero `create_object` is returning an `OriginalClass` instance. You don't control `create_object`, but at the same time you really want it to return a `MyClass` instance. Can you see that is not possible? You need to have some additional logic to transform your output.

Comment: I understand. But, would be possible to perform a casting? Something like in Java, `self = (MyClass) create_obect()`, and still being able to access the inherited attributes. Also, the main motive to have a different class is to not override the original one, and also point out that this class is a modified version of the original.

Comment: @rober_dinero By using `obj.__class__ = MyClass` you're in fact doing an upcast. What's the problem with using it?

Comment: I see... I am just still wondering if there is a way to not carry those extra lines at the end of the class or a function wrapping them. For now this will be the way I will proceed.

Comment: You can add a decorator to `create_object` if you want the cast to be performed automatically... @rober_dinero

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the original code, I would have implemented the `create_object` functions as class methods.

```
class SqueezeNet(nn.Module):
    ...

    @classmethod
    def squeezenet1_0(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        def squeezenet1_0(pretrained: bool = False, progress: bool = True, **kwargs: Any) -> SqueezeNet:
        return cls._squeezenet('1_0', pretrained, progress, **kwargs)

    @classmethod
    def squeezenet1_1(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        def squeezenet1_0(pretrained: bool = False, progress: bool = True, **kwargs: Any) -> SqueezeNet:
        return cls._squeezenet('1_1', pretrained, progress, **kwargs)

    @classmethod
    def _squeezenet(cls, version: str, pretrained: bool, progress: bool, **kwargs: Any) -> SqueezeNet:
        model = cls(version, **kwargs)
        if pretrained:
            arch = 'squeezenet' + version
            state_dict = load_state_dict_from_url(model_urls[arch],
                                                  progress=progress)
            model.load_state_dict(state_dict)
        return model
```

So what does the class method do? It just instantiates the object as normal, but then calls a particular method on it before returning it. As such, there's nothing to *do* in your subclass. Calling `MySqueezeNetSubclass._squeezenet` would instantiate your *subclass*, not `SqueezeNet`. If you need to customize anything else, you can override `_squeezenet` in your own class, using `super()._squeezenet` to do the parent creation first before modifying the result.

```
class MySubclass(SqueezeNet):
    @classmethod
    def _squeezenet(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        model = super()._squeezenet(*args, **kwargs)
        # Do MySubclass-specific things to model here
        return model
```

---

But, `_squeezenet` isn't a class method; it's a regular function. There's not much you can do except patch it at runtime, which is hopefully something you can do before anything tries to call it. For example,

```
import torchvision.models.squeezenet

def _new_squeezenet(version, pertained, progress, **kwargs):
    model = MySqueezeNetSubClass(version, **kwarsg)
    # Maybe more changes specific to your code here. Specifically,
    # you might want to provide your own URL rather than one from
    # model_urls, etc.
    if pretrained:
        arch = 'squeezenet' + version
        state_dict = load_state_dict_from_url(model_urls[arch],
                                              progress=progress)
        model.load_state_dict(state_dict)
    return model


torchvision.models.squeezenet._squeezenet = _new_squeezenet
```

The lesson here is that not everything is designed to be easily subclassed.

Comment: Actually, I want to modify the object after `_squeezenet` gets called. All the logic in there will remain unchanged. The functionality could be decomposed in two. First, instantiate the net (with the `_squeezenet` logic), the most important parameter is `pretrained` (loading pretrained network or untrained network). Second, adapt some layers of the instantiated object (`model`) to a specific use case. Being more specific, this model was trained using RGB images and I want to use it with single-channel, thus the expected input parameter of one of its attributes should be changed from 3 to 1.

Comment: The key is that the function is hard-coded to instantiate `SqueezeNet`. At worst, you can simply duplicate that function, but replacing `SqueezeNet` with your own class. That's why I said I would have defined `_squeezenet` and its version-specific wrappers as class methods, because that's almost the *raison d'être* for class methods: to provide alternate constructors without hard-coding the class being constructed.

Comment: I understand! So just to wrap it up, it could be viewed as the language not being expressive enough to perform those changes (taking the code as is)? Or, it is a consequence of a poorly design choice?

Comment: I'm leaning toward poor design choice (though "poor" is too strong; the authors are under no obligation to design a class for inheritance).